# git and subversion's plugin on the same IDE

Tags: visual-studio, git, svn, version-control

Is it possible to use two different source control plugins on the same IDE?

(subversion and git)

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is.
VS will usually figure out which source control addin to use for each project.

If it doesn't, you can tell it which one to use by clicking Tools, Options, Source Control.